# How do you handle foreign key in react form POST?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

Hello guys I am trying to write a submit form in React where a client can fill up their dog's information and eventually submit the booking form to make a reservation and post the data to db (oracle).

To be specific, I want to have the client to write their dog's name (not the dog's id but dog id is the foreign key in Grooming_Booking).I have no idea how should I handle it on my react code. Here is what I have

in my java bean (I just didn't include getter and setter) and service:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Grooming_booking")
public class GroomingBooking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "gbsg")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "gbsg", sequenceName = "Grooming_Booking_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dog_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Dog dog;


public boolean addReservation(DaycampReservation daycampReservation) {
        try {
            daycampReservationDao.save(daycampReservation);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my React

```
class GroomingForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            newGrooming: {
                startTime:'',
                decription: '',
                dog:{
                    id: 0,
                    name:''
                }
            }
        };
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const callback = (response) => {
            if (response.data.success) {
                alert('update successfully!');
            } else {
                alert('update failed...');
            }
        };
        this.props.addGrooming(this.state.newGrooming, callback);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let {name, value, type} = event.target;
        if (type === 'number') {
            value = +value; // convert string to number. '1' -> 1
        }
        this.state.newGrooming[name] = value;
        this.setState(
            {
                newGrooming: this.state.newGrooming
            }
        );
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="formGridAddress1">
                        <Form.Label>Dog Name</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control required placeholder="Your Dog's Name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.newGrooming.dog.name}/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group controlId="formGridAddress1">
                        <Form.Label>Dog ID</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="number" required placeholder="Your Dog's ID" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.newGrooming.dog.id}/>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="formGridStartTime">
                        <Form.Label>Start Time</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control required type="datetime-local" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.00" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.newGrooming.startTime}/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                        <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={4} placeholder="Anything to add" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.newGrooming.decription} />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect(null, {addGrooming})(GroomingForm);
```

Can I declare dog's name but not id in this.state even though it's the foreign key? If so, what would be the way to do so?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdeHF.png)
I appreciate your time reading my question.

Comment: It isn't good practice to have React, which is your client-side library handle anything related to your backend. It should have no concept of what is or isn't a foreign key, those values should be passed over to the backend through the body or params of your post request and later handled only through the backend. Unfortunately without further context of what your API or your relational DB  tables look like it is hard to say what would the best way to do this be.

Comment: I attached my db diagram if it helps. I just wanna know if what I have in my react component is the right way. I assumed I had to include id since it's the foreign key.